# How can I programmatically set the rosconsole verbosity of an object?

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a local planner plugin that instantiates a `base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS` object and then calls `checkTrajectory` on it. Specifically, this is the function that gets called eventually: `TrajectoryPlanner::checkTrajectory` ([link to source code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/base_local_planner/src/trajectory_planner.cpp#L515-L529))

During execution of my local planner, that function is called a lot in order to evaluate velocity command candidates. As a result, it spams this warning:

```
ROS_WARN("Invalid Trajectory %f, %f, %f, cost: %f", vx_samp, vy_samp, vtheta_samp, cost);
```

I know that, from the command line, I can call the `set_loggers` service of the corresponding node in order to set the logger level to `ERROR` and thus prevent the spamming.

Is there a way to set the logger level when I instantiate the `TrajectoryPlannerROS` object in my local planner?

I would like to **avoid**:

- making a service call (whether programmatic or via the command line)
- forking `base_local_planner` and changing the `ROS_WARN` to `ROS_DEBUG`

The `rosconsole` wiki page has some relevant info, but it seems overkill for what I want to achieve. (Although I've never used anything but the `ROS_*` macros, so it may just be lack of familiarity.)

References:

- http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole
- http://answers.ros.org/question/211961/how-to-avoid-invalid-trajectory-cost-1000000-in-dwa-local-planner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250297/how-can-i-programmatically-set-the-rosconsole-verbosity-of-an-object?/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosconsole page that you link to has a section on [setting the logger level](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Changing_Logger_Levels) that includes some example C++ code for changing the logger level. Is this what you're looking for?

If you want to change the logger level for the entire DWA local planner, you might want to consider switching all of its logger macros to use the named logger macros. This will allow you to the logger level for DWA separately from the rest of your code. This is probably a useful enough change that it would be worth submitting it into the public ROS navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-12-19**:
This excerpt from [example.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/tools/rosconsole/examples/example.cpp) does look promising: `log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME".test");` I'll start there. Thanks Austin!